# mysqldump for UNIX domain socket

Tags: backup, database, mysql

I have setup a new mysql database with my webhosting provider and the hostname is not the default localhost it is localhost:/tmp/mysql5.sock

I think this is becuase they are moving from mysql 4 to mysql 5

My question is how do I use mysqldump to create a backup file of this database, what ever I try gives me wrong username or can not connect errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are referring to is called a [UNIX domain socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket).

A socket is an alternative communication method to TCP/IP.

You can point `mysqldump` to it with the following flag:

```
--socket=/tmp/mysql5.sock
```

Additionally you should update the socket location in your MySQL configuration - `my.cnf`.

Sockets are preferred over TCP/IP for local connections.

So if `my.cnf` is correct, then you shouldn't need to specify the location in the `mysqldump` command, or for other applications that utilise the MySQL configuration.